# vcgencmd in buildroot

Tags: video, kernel, buildroot

I am using buildroot to create a custom os for my raspberry pi. I would like to use the vcgencmd command, but I am unable to find the package that includes these tools. I have tried searching the internet and found that it could be part of VideoCore (which I also cannot find), raspberrypi-firmware (also not present).

So my question is: how to I include the vcgencmd tools in a custom build? What is the package name?

Answer (score 1):

The current version of buildroot provides this under a slightly different name. Under xconfig or menuconfig...

```
Target packages -> Hardware handling -> Firmware -> rpi-firmware
```

Looking inside the corresponding tarball, there is indeed a `vcgencmd` binary in there.

Comment: You found a binary but buildroot is compiling from source, isn't it?

Comment: Buildroot will usually cross-compile packages for the chosen target platform, but there's nothing preventing a buildroot package from specifying that certain arbitrary files be copied into the target image directly -- it's just that this would be a bad idea for executables if you didn't know what architecture the user was building for. I haven't looked at this in a while, but in the case of rpi firmware it doesn't seem unreasonable that the binaries would be prebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

vcgencmd is included in libraspberrypi-bin.

All the Pi specific packages are in the Foundation's repository.

If you're running Raspbian you can find the apt source in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`
Current contents (for Raspbian Stretch) is

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

Comment: Buildroot is not Raspbian and doesn't use apt packages like libraspberrypi-bin.